# SharePoint AD FS with multiple web applications

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, adfs, relying-party-trust

I have two web applications, both set to authenticate via ADFS.  The first one, ConnectTo, works fine.  However the second one, MySites, always redirects to the first.

Here are my Relying Party Trustsin ADFS:

[image: Relying Party Trusts]

**Here are the ConnectTo Relying Party Trust's Identifiers and endpoints.  I have tried this with and without the URL identifier** 
(https://connectto.sp2013dev.com/_trust/).

[image: ConnectTo Identifiers]
[image: ConnectTo Endpoints]

**Here are the MySites Relying Party Trust's Identifiers and endpoints.  I have tried this with and without the URL identifier** 
(https://mysites.sp2013dev.com/_trust/).

[image: MySites Identifiers]
[image: MySites Endpoints]

In SharePoint, I have configured my trustedIdentityTokenIssuer and it works great for the first Web Application, ConnectTo.  However, I am unable to add a second Web Application.  The second web app, Mysites, is always redirected to ConnectTo once the user is authenticated.

Here are my provider realms as configured in my `SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer`, configured via the following command:

```
$id1 = "urn:sharepoint:MySites"
$uri1 = new-object System.Uri("https://mysites.sp2013dev.com")
$id2 = "urn:sharepoint:ConnectTo"
$uri2 = new-object System.Uri("https:// connectto.sp2013dev.com")

$ap.ProviderRealms.Add($uri1, $id1)
$ap.ProviderRealms.Add($uri2, $id2)
$ap.Update()
```

********************** EDIT ********************************

I have since removed the duplicate ConnectTo Provider Realm per @Waqas Sarwar MCSE suggestion.

[image: Provider Realms 2]

********************** EDIT ********************************

And here is the rest of my `SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer`, just in case.

[image: SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer]

The URL when I connect to the MySites WebApp is as follows:

> https://sts.sp2013dev.com/adfs/ls?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3asharepoint%3aConnectTo&wctx=http%3a%2f%2fmysites.sp2013dev.com%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F

The `wtream` is `urn:sharepoint:ConnectTo` but I assume that is because my default realm in the `SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer` is `urn:sharepoint:ConnectTo`.  Could this be my problem?

If I add the MySites endpoint as the default endpoint to the ConnectTo Relying Party Trust, ConnectTo.sp2013dev.com is redirected to mysites.sp2013dev.com.   Thus I feel my issue is with the provider realms of the `SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer` but I really cannot figure out this issue.  Could someone provide insight as to why my configuration is incorrect?  Thank you!

Comment: looks like duplicate entries for connectto, try to remove connecto..$uri2 = new-object System.Uri("https:// connectto.sp2013dev.com") ....$ap = ProviderRealms.Remove($uri2)

Comment: could you please check, if not ADFS authetnication configured for mysite and you can able to login using your windows credential...also check the AAM settings..also check if you have host file which redirect to connectto site....i am thinking may be DNS not properly configured or aamor host file

Comment: I removed the mysite provider realm but did not see a change.  I reset the claims to windows token service, IIS, and the sharepoint timer.   Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Also, Windows authentication works fine, the issue only occurs with ADFS authentication and I verified that my update to the provider realm actually stuck.

Comment: The URL when I connect to the MySites WebApp is as follows: https://sts.sp2013dev.com/adfs/ls?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3asharepoint%3aConnectTo&wctx=http%3a%2f%2fmysites.sp2013dev.com%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F   The wtream in the URL is urn:sharepoint:ConnectTo but I assume that is because my default realm in the SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer is urn:sharepoint:ConnectTo. Could this be my problem?

Comment: You have two entries in your realm for connectto....intially when you setup the ADFS, first one automatically configured as your provirode $realam...2nd you need to configure a seprate package for MySite and add it....

Comment: What do you mean separate package?

Comment: separate relying party...i think you already did that....just remove the duplicate connectto entry

Comment: We have this problem with the SSL cert on the web servers. If you navigate to one of our production websites. Regardless of what site you enter in the URL, if it is https, it goes to one specific web application. Currently working to resolve it. I'll try to post the process if you would find it helpful. http works just fine. Internally, we do not use SSL because we monitor traffic with Tipping Point.

Comment: Any update after removing duplicate entry and separate relying party packaged

Comment: any news, if you able to fix it or not?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE, Could you add your suggestion as an answer?  I'd like to award the bounty to you.  I'm not sure exactly what the cause was, I had to rebuild the entire SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer and it worked (I used the same commands, not sure what changed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like duplicate entries for `connectto`, So Please removes duplicate entry using the following PowerShell

```
$uri2 = new-object System.Uri("https:// connectto.sp2013dev.com")
$ap = ProviderRealms.Remove($uri2)
```

I would highly recommend that create the separate relying party package for each web application and then configure it in SharePoint.

Comment: Note that separate Relying Party Trust for each Web Application is not required if using ADFS 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Add the MySites as a separate relying party, it's one extra roundtrip but any authenticated user will be immediately sent to the MySites without having to log on again.

Comment: Mysites is a separate relying party.  Thanks though!

Comment: And set the identifier in the MySite relying party to "urn:sharepoint:MySites" ;-)

Comment: The identifier in the MySites relying party is 'urn:sharepoint:MySites'

Comment: In the MySites relying party, use urn:sharepoint:mysites as the identifier (realm), in the connectto use urn:sharepoint:connectto. Remove all other identifiers

Comment: I had tried that too (actually first), where the only identifier was the urn for each relying party trust.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually we had the same issue, and the way we fixed it is by making sure that the alternative access mapping for all of the applications is HTTPS and all mention of HTTP URLs is removed, additionally we did this for those sites in IIS, so they were running on HTTPS only, again with all HTTP urls removed